# Why cannot find event string command, where it is in history?

Tags: bash, command-history

Is there a limit in number of commands through which does event string `!?command` look?:

```
user@Host:~/Desktop/bin$ !?strace -o!
bash: !?strace -o!: event not found
user@Host:~/Desktop/bin$ history 100 | grep strace
 1964  man strace
 1989  strace -o >(vim -) a.out ##there you go, command I look after
 1990  man strace | grep -A5 "^\s*-p"
 1994  man strace | grep -A5 "^\s*-e"
 1998  man strace | grep -A5 "^\s*-e"
 2000  history 100 | grep strace
user@Host:~/Desktop/bin$
```

The even `!?strace -o!` was not found, yet it is in history of commands, so why?

Also, why isn't  possible to use regex in `!?regex_to_find_command?` ? That would make much easier to look-up already used commands. (E.g. used `!?strace .*?`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The syntax](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Event-Designators.html) is

```
!?strace -o?
```

or

```
!?strace -o
```

You need to use a closing question mark, not exclamation mark. The question mark can be omitted if you end the search criterion with a newline.